# if condition in the razor syntax for HTML table- MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a HTML table with 2 rows and 4 columns. The data in each cell is coming from the stored proc. Currently, the last column displays number, I have an image to display, but it has to be displayed only if(rejected_question>0) else it should not display anything. How do I accomplish this in razor.

I have tried this so far, the below code doesn't work:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
        {
//logic for first three columns..
//fourth column here.
<td align="center">
                    if(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RejectedQuestion) >0)
                   {
                    return Html.Raw(string.Format("<text><img height='3' width='3' src="\{0}\" alt="\Image\" /></text>", Url.Content("../../content/images/icon_red_questions_returnedbyreviewer.gif")));
                    }
</td>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what your looking for, probably:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    //logic for first three columns..
    //fourth column here.
    <td align="center">
        @if(item.RejectedQuestion > 0)
        {
            <img height="3" width="3" alt="Image"
                 src="@Url.Content("~/content/images/icon_red_questions_returnedbyreviewer.gif")" />
        }
    </td>
}
```

Comment: I tried your approach, it displays the if condition also, along with the image, am i missing something?

Comment: Woops. Sorry. Forgot the `@` in front of the `if`. I'll fix the answer.

Comment: Sorry, agian James didn't work. error is: > operator cannot be applied to type string and int

Comment: I presumed "RejectQuestion" was an int. Apparently, according to your comment, it's a string. You would then do a comparison as item.RejectedQuestion > "0", if that's what you want

Comment: Thanks!! fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Make the line inside the if statement

```
@Html.Raw(string.Format("<text><img height='3' width='3' src="\{0}\" alt="\Image\" /></text>", Url.Content("../../content/images/icon_red_questions_returnedbyreviewer.gif")))
```

to display it. view.Execute() returns void, so you cannot include a return statement.

Comment: Did you mean this: if(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RejectedQuestion) >0)
                   {
                     Html.Raw(string.Format("<text><img height='3' width='3' src="\{0}\" alt="\Image\" /></text>", Url.Content("../../content/images/icon_red_questions_returnedbyreviewer.gif")));
                    }. If so, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked, just in case if someone needs it in future
:

```
@if(item.RejectedQuestion > 0)
                    {
                    <img height="20" width="20" alt="Image"
                         src="@Url.Content("~/content/images/icon_red_questions_returnedbyreviewer.gif")" />
                }
```